# Dataset for vector autoregression in R

Tags: r, dataset, vector-autoregression

I am using R for vector autoregression. I can't find data that can fit the model. Can you help me please? Or can you suggest another alternative such as how to get my own data?

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you want to try out how a VAR works and need data for that?

Comment: Yes
i want to put data in R so that i can build the VAR model using R. 
i tried with different data using the function VAR in R but it is not working.

Comment: Apparently, asking for data is off-topic on Cross Validated. You should rather try [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/). But if you only wanted to experiment with whatever data for a VAR model, then I hope I have answered your question already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dataset `Canada` in "vars" package in R. The dataset is used as an example dataset to illustrate how different functions in that package work. You can create the data variable called `Canada` by typing `data(Canada)`. From then on you can use `Canada` for creating a VAR model using the function `VAR`. For example,

```
data(Canada)
model=VAR(Canada,3)
```

will estimate a VAR(3) model for the variables contained in `Canada`. You can view the estimated model by typing `print(model)`.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you so much Sir.
You have been of a great help.

Comment: You are most welcome! I am glad it worked.